# How to put an Icon Button at the top left corner in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to display the the IconButton at the top left corner but it's getting dipslayed at the middle like this[image]

What I want is , that, it should get displayed at top corner, its a back which navigates back to previous screen. Following is the code of my Screen

package com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.screens

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.R
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.constants.Destinations

@Composable
fun OnBoardingScreen3(navController: NavController) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .padding(top = 36.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        // Back icon at the top-left corner
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 2.dp, top = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = Color(0xFF039be5)
            )
        }

        // Add bold text below the image
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start, // Align the text to the left
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Your data and privacy",

                // mc-serif/headline-large
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 32.sp,
                    lineHeight = 40.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000),
                )
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Text(
                text = "You choose what data you share. It’s transferred and stored securely",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                fontSize = 16.sp
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id =
                    R.drawable.safety),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp), // Adjust the
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                )

                Text(
                    text = "At Mayo Clinic, we take data privacy very seriously",

                            // mc-serif/display-small-light
                            style = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = 40.sp,
                    lineHeight = 44.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(300),
                    color = Color(0xFF080808),
                )
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Text(
                text = "Participation is voluntary and you can withdraw from a study at any time.",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                fontSize = 16.sp
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Text(
                text = " If results of a study are made public, you won’t be able to be identified.",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                fontSize = 16.sp
            )

            // Add image and text below "Your data and privacy"
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        }

        // Remaining text elements
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        // Add more text elements here as needed
    }
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        // Spacer to push the button to the bottom
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        // Button centered at the bottom
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(Destinations.OnBoardingScreen4)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(120.dp)
                .padding(top = 40.dp, bottom = 40.dp)
                .height(50.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xFF039be5))
        ) {
            Text(text = "Next", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, style =
            TextStyle(Color.White))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `Icon` inside `Box()`:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
                  .fillMaxWidth()
                  .padding(start = 2.dp, top = 8.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart)
{
    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color(0xFF039be5)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to put this Above the Column but there are no changes, Can you share the entire modified code of the screen?

Comment: Not above the column, just copy this code and replace it with `IconButton(){...}` code

Comment: Hi, I implemented this code and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun OnBoardingScreen3(navController: NavController) { 
    //...   
    Column {

       TopAppBar(
           title = { Text(title) },
           navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = navController.popBackStack()) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                         contentDescription = null,
                         tint = Color(0xFF039be5))
                }
            },
            actions = {
               // action menus here
            }
      )
      // your screen here
      YourScreenHere()
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use TopAppBar

Comment: @TejasKhartude why not allowed? If it is for experimental use then just add `@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)` above function. similar to my answer.

Comment: No, my client requires it to look like this, no TopAppbar nothing, just plain Incon at left corner

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row and add IconButton and Text As Below. I have given Text weight 1 so it will occupy the required size only.

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Complete Code**

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.jetpackcomposeplayground.ui.theme.JetpackComposePlayGroundTheme

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Ex19Preview() {
    JetpackComposePlayGroundTheme {
        Ex19()
    }
}


@Composable
fun Ex19() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.White),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
//            navigateUp()
            }) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                contentDescription = "Back",
            )
        }
        Text(text = "Custom title", modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(1f))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the Modifier for the IconButton.

```
IconButton(
            onClick = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 2.dp, top = 8.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Start) // Align to top-left corner

        ) {
```