# Why is my Text content overlapping over the Text Title and not below the Text Title in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to display Text content below the Text Title in android using jetpack compose. Currently , the content is getting displayed but it's overlapping everywhere on the Title like this
[image]

I want the content of the screen to be below it's title "Advancing Healthcare". What am I  doing wrong here in this code? Below is the code written by me.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.constants.Destinations


@Composable
fun OnBoardingScreen2(navController: NavController) {
    // Back icon at the top-left corner
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
        ,contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart,
    ) {
        // Back icon at the top-left corner
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 2.dp, top = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = Color(0xFF0057B8)
            )
        }
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(start = 22.dp, end = 21.dp)
            .padding(top = 120.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        // Add bold text below the image
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Advancing healthcare",
            // mc-serif/headline-large
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                lineHeight = 40.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                color = Color(0xFF000000),
            )
        )
    }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(start = 22.dp, end =21.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "What if the use of everyday devices—your phone,your watch—could help identify early warning signs of Alzheimer’s?",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    lineHeight = 28.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000),
            )
            )

            Text(
                text = "What if a clinician could diagnose Cardiovascular disease using only your voice?",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    lineHeight = 24.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000),
            ),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 6.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = "The information collected from wearables and devices,are transforming how we detect and approach diseases, offering early insights and more personalized care.",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    lineHeight = 24.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000),
            ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 10.dp)

            )

        }
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(20.dp)
        ) {
            // Spacer to push the button to the bottom
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

            // Button centered at the bottom
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(Destinations.OnBoardingScreen3)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(top = 12.dp, bottom = 20.dp, start =
                    24.dp, end = 24.dp)
                    .height(48.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xFF0057B8))
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Next",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    style = TextStyle(Color.White)
                )
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you took me wrong in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77022463/19212377)

Here is your updated code(please update paddings according to your requirements):

```
@Composable
fun OnBoardingScreen2(navController: NavController?) {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        // Back icon at the top-left corner
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 120.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart,
        ) {
            // Back icon at the top-left corner
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    navController?.popBackStack()
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 2.dp, top = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = Color(0xFF0057B8)
                )
            }
        }
        // Add bold text below the image
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(70.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Advancing healthcare",
            // mc-serif/headline-large
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 32.sp,
                lineHeight = 40.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                color = Color(0xFF000000),
            )
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Text(
            text = "What if the use of everyday devices—your phone,your watch—could help identify early warning signs of Alzheimer’s?",
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                lineHeight = 28.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                color = Color(0xFF000000),
            )
        )

        Text(
            text = "What if a clinician could diagnose Cardiovascular disease using only your voice?",
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                lineHeight = 24.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                color = Color(0xFF000000),
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 6.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = "The information collected from wearables and devices,are transforming how we detect and approach diseases, offering early insights and more personalized care.",
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                lineHeight = 24.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                color = Color(0xFF000000),
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 10.dp)

        )


        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(20.dp)
        ) {
            // Spacer to push the button to the bottom
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier)

            // Button centered at the bottom
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    //navController.navigate(Destinations.OnBoardingScreen3)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(
                        top = 12.dp, bottom = 20.dp, start =
                        24.dp, end = 24.dp
                    )
                    .height(48.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xFF0057B8))
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Next",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    style = TextStyle(Color.White)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyl0g.jpg)

Comment: Thank you, I understood what I was missing...